# vertically distribute multiple lines with smart spacing

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, plyr

A common display of spectroscopic data (intensity vs wavelength) is used below to compare the position of peaks in the data across multiple spectra. Assuming they all share a baseline at 0, it is convenient to offset the multiple lines vertically by a constant spacing, to avoid the distraction of overlapping lines.

[image]

Thus becomes

[image]

I'm looking for a better strategy to perform this vertical shift automatically, starting from data in long format. Here is a minimal example.

```
# fake data (5 similar-looking spectra)
spec <- function(){
  x <- runif(100, 0, 100)
  data.frame(x=x, y=jitter(dnorm(x, mean=jitter(50), sd=jitter(5)), amount=0.01))
}
require(plyr)
all <- ldply(1:5, function(ii) data.frame(spec(), id=ii))
```

My current strategy is as follows:

- convert the spectra from long format to wide format. This involves interpolation, as the spectra do not necessarily have identical x axis values.
- find the minimum offset between spectra to avoid overlap between neighbours
- shift the spectra by multiples of this distance
- melt back to long format

I implemented this using plyr,

```
# function that evenly spaces the spectra to avoid overlap
# d is in long format, s is a scaling factor for the vertical shift
require(plyr); require(ggplot2)

spread_plot <- function(d, s=1){
  ranges <- ddply(d, "id", with, each(min,max,length)(x))
  common_x <- seq(max(ranges$min), min(ranges$max), length=max(ranges$length))
  new_y <- dlply(d, "id", function(x) approx(x$x, x$y, common_x)$y)
  mat <- do.call(cbind, new_y)
  test <- apply(mat, 1, diff)
  shift <- max(-test[test < 0])
  origins <- s*seq(0, by=shift, length=ncol(mat))

  for(ii in seq_along(origins)){
    current <- unique(d[["id"]])[ii]
    d[d[["id"]] == current, "y"] <- 
      d[d[["id"]] == current, "y"] + origins[ii]
  }
  d
}

test <- spread_plot(all)

ggplot(test, aes(x, y, colour=id, group=id))+
  geom_line() + guides(colour=guide_legend())
```

This strategy suffers from a few shortcomings:

- it is slow
- the offset is not a pretty number; I do not know how to automatically round it well so that spectra are offset e.g. by 0.02, or 50, etc. depending on the range of the intensities. `pretty(origins)` is problematic in that it can return a different number of values.

I feel I'm missing a simpler solution, perhaps working directly with the original data in long format.

Comment: Typically such spectra exhibit identical x values. Is that really not the case for yours?

Comment: in my case it's Raman spectra acquired at different laser excitation wavelengths, so the dispersion of the gratings results in slightly different wavenumbers.

Comment: now, bonus points if this is made into a new position_xxx() function for ggplot2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question.

Here's a possibility, offered without detailed comment, except to point out that it:

- Should be very fast, due to a combo of its avoidance of **plyr**, use of **data.table**, and operation on data in its original long format.
- Uses `pretty()` to pick a pretty offset.
- Like your code, is not guaranteed to produce no intersections of lines, since overlap can happen between the lattice of points formed by `common_x`.

Here's the code

```
## Setup
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

spec <- function(){
  x <- runif(100, 0, 100)
  data.frame(x=x, y=jitter(dnorm(x, mean=jitter(50), sd=jitter(5)), amount=0.01))
}
all <- ldply(1:5, function(ii) data.frame(spec(), id=ii))

## Function that uses data.table rather than plyr to compute and add offsets
spread_plot <- function(d, s=1){
    d <- data.table(d, key="id")
    ranges <- d[, list(min=min(x), max=max(x), length=length(x)),by="id"]
    common_x <- seq(max(ranges$min), min(ranges$max), length=max(ranges$length))
    new_y <- d[,list(y=approx(x, y, common_x)$y, N=seq_along(common_x)),
               by="id"]
    shift <- max(new_y[, max(abs(diff(y))), by = "N"][[2]])
    shift <- pretty(c(0, shift), n=0)[2]
    origins <- s*seq(0, by=shift, length=length(unique(d$id)))
    d[,y:=(y + origins[.GRP]),by="id"]
    d
}

## Try it out
test <- spread_plot(all)
ggplot(test, aes(x, y, colour=id, group=id))+
  geom_line() + guides(colour=guide_legend())
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, that looks pretty straight-forward even for a non-DT user. The only thing I would need to read up on is this `.GRP`, but its meaning is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I still think you could rely on some assumptions about typical data from spectroscopy. Usually, x values are sorted, the number of them is equal for all spectra and they are quite similar:

```
# new fake data (5 similar-looking spectra)
spec <- function(){
  x <- jitter(seq(0,100,1),0.1)
  data.frame(x=x, y=jitter(dnorm(x, mean=jitter(50), sd=jitter(5)), amount=0.01))
}
require(plyr)
all <- ldply(1:5, function(ii) data.frame(spec(), id=ii))
```

If these assumptions are valid, you could treat the spectra as having identical x values:

```
library(ggplot2)
spread_plot  <- function(d, s=0.05) {
  #add some checks here, e.g., for equal length 
  d <- d[order(d$x),]
  d$id <- factor(d$id)
  l <- levels(d$id)
  pretty_offset <- pretty(s*min(tapply(d$y, d$id, function(x) abs(diff(range(x))))))[2]

  for (i in seq_len(length(l)-1)+1) {
      mean_delta_y <- mean(d[d$id == l[i], "y"] - d[d$id == l[i-1], "y"])
      d[d$id == l[i], "y"] <-  d[d$id == l[i], "y"] - mean_delta_y
      min_delta_y <- abs(1.05 * min(d[d$id == l[i], "y"] - d[d$id == l[i-1], "y"]))
      pretty_delta_y <- max(min_delta_y, pretty_offset)
      d[d$id == l[i], "y"] <-  d[d$id == l[i], "y"] + pretty_delta_y
      }
  p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, col=id)) + geom_line()
  print(p)
}
spread_plot(all, s=0)
```

[image]

```
spread_plot(all, s=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: good points regarding the set of reasonable assumptions. The data.table solution is more compact and presumably faster but it's good to see alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by hadley, the for loop can be avoided very simply,

```
d$y <- d$y + origins[d$id]
```

Full code:

```
spread_plot <- function(d, s=1){
  ranges <- ddply(d, "id", with, each(min,max,length)(x))
  common_x <- seq(max(ranges$min), min(ranges$max), length=max(ranges$length))
  new_y <- dlply(d, "id", function(x) approx(x$x, x$y, common_x)$y)
  mat <- do.call(cbind, new_y)
  test <- apply(mat, 1, diff)
  shift <- max(-test[test < 0])
  origins <- s*seq(0, by=shift, length=ncol(mat))

  d$y <- d$y + origins[d$id]

  d
}

test <- spread_plot(all)

ggplot(test, aes(x, y, colour=id, group=id))+
  geom_line() + guides(colour=guide_legend())
```

[image]